# Can't fit Pi zero W into Adafruit's case

Tags: pi-zero-w, case

I bought a package of Pi zero W in [here](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3411) and it comes with a case made from Adafruit, but when I'm assembling Zero W into case I found out there is a piece that bump out at the back inside the case (the side where you can connect pins on zero W but it's on case) and if you put that piece under Pi, Pi can't nicely fits in, but if you want to match the four side it provide to lock you Pi in place you can't because you can't put your Pi under the bump out piece

How to solve it, shoud that piece be above or bellow Pi or should I chop it of

Here is the image look at the red circle

[image]

Comment: @Steve Ok I'll put it later my issue is that I can't slide it under the piece b/c It have two satnd out piece to lock the Pi but it also cause me I can't slide Pi in because it bumps into the way

Comment: I'll try it but since I have only 1 rep. I can't post two photos, I'm sorry, here is the link to case's ppicture [here](https://files.andrewyg.net/img/630.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this place the Pi in the case with the HDMI side down so it will slot into the matching holes for the HDMI, USB and power, and line up over the pins that match the holes in the Pi. You can then push down firmly and the board should push the little hooked bar out of the way alowing the pi to sit flat in the case, (the little hook is designed to hold the pi securely). if necessary you can use a small piece of wood or plastic to push the little hook back out of the way while doing this to make it a little easier.

As you can see in this photo:

[image: adafruit pi zero enclosure]

the little hook clearly fits over the Pi.

To remove the Pi, push or pull the hook back and push up on the board, A popsicle stick or spludger makes this much easier.

Comment: Is this Pi zero or Pi zero W??

Comment: In the pic is a Pi but the adafruit product page says this: This enclosure is only compatible with the Raspberry Pi Zero and Pi Zero W! It works with both the Zero v1.2 and v1.3 with camera connector as well as the Wireless Pi Zero W

Comment: I made it by pushing it a bit harder, since I just get Pi yesterday, and base on my experience I'm afraid I'll break the chip if I force it to slide in but the result said it can slide in but you need to put your afraidness aside Thanks Steve!

Comment: But now I have issue to bring it out, is there tips since currently I only find you can touch and pull it out by port is there any nicer way?

Answer (score 1):

Gently pushing the tabs out of the way seems to be the key. I had success using a Swiss Army nail file/flat-head screwdriver blade, but a plastic flat-head screwdriver or something similar is probably the safest option.